# Why Do I need to use Custom Event for Tooltip and Brush in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have tried to break down the code for applying tooltip on the brush in D3.

And the code I'm looking into seems like using custom event.
However, I don't see the custom event is that necessary. To check this, I commented out
the entire custom event part and it worked perfectly fine.

The part I commented out is below.

```
function brushend() {
    //딱히 필요한거같지는 않은 기능.
  get_button = d3.select(".clear-button");
  if(get_button.empty() === true) {
    clear_button = svg.append('text')
      .attr("y", 460)
      .attr("x", 825)
      .attr("class", "clear-button")
      .text("Clear Brush");
  }
```

The entire code is attached below.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/NWGXoQo

I think it's just an extra piece which doesn't do anything on the visualization.

What makes a difference here that enables tooltip on top of the brush function is 
happening here I strongly believe.

> It adds the helper function in the manner of 'call' instead of just
>   adding  '.on('click', function() )'

```
points = svg.selectAll(".point")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("r", function(d){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1) + 5);})
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.index); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .call(d3.helping.tooltip());
```

Thank you in advance.

P.S
In addition, as far as I understand, 
Custom event is not really necessary in any situation.
Cause what it does is just same as regular function and custom events
can't really do anything special. To execute its functionality I need to dispatch it 
which makes the code lengthy, no more than that.

This is just my thought and I'm willing to hear any critics on my thought.(It's not my main question)

Always feel grateful about constructive comments from Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.
It wasn't a matter of custom event.
It was a matter of the ordder of code and calling function only.